# Why we need to copy-and-paste functions declaration into inherited class header

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, coding-style

This is for C++.

Usually we have our function declaration in header file and definition in source file.
Say we have a class A with some functions:

```
//< A.hpp
class A
{
public:
   virtual funcA();
   virtual funcB();
}
```

And we want to have a class inherit from A and override its functions.

```
//< childA.hpp
class childA
{
   virtual funcA();
   virtual funcB();
}
```

Everytime we change the declarations of `funcA() funcB()`, we need to copy-and-paste the new declarations to the child classes header files. If the inheritance chain is long, it's quite bother.

I remember we don't have this problem with Object-C, do we?

Comment: Why would you copy **defintions** to child class header files ? I think you meant declarations. If the child class has virtual function, it's source file is going to provide the implementation. If not, base class virtual function is going to get called. Remember that, it isn't pure virtual member function.

Comment: Corrected, it should be declaration instead of definition. Sorry for the confusion. Yes, if the declaration changed in the parent class, we need to modify the child class source file since it may have different implementation. But we also need to modify the child class header file, which have the same code in the parent class header file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to copy a member function declaration to the child class's header file unless you want to override it. In that case, I believe the main reason you're required to declare it is to inform anyone reading your header file that the child class is providing a different implementation. In principle, the compiler can figure it out automatically, but it could be a real pain for a human to do the same thing manually.

Note that in many cases, people reading your header files may not have access to the actual source code for the body (e.g., if it's a proprietary library that is delivered to them as compiled objects), so they can't just go look at the body to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks jjlin, this is somewhat reasonable, but since if people can access the source code, he should be able to know which member functions are overridden. If people only read header files, since the declaration is exactly the same, one still has no clue on what the child class do.

Comment: I actually edited my answer to address your point about having source code access, but you probably hadn't seen it when you posted your comment. As for the declaration being exactly the same, one would hope that the comments aren't exactly the same as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

From the Objective-C article on Wikipedia:

> Objective-C, like Smalltalk, can use dynamic typing: an object can be sent a message that is not specified in its interface.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_typing

C++, on the other hand, is **statically typed**.  It's a stricter compile-time restraint.

Comment: Thanks chroipahtz. You are right, C++ is not pure OO. I had been using C++ for some time, but I never noticed this annoying point before. I am wondering if there is any tricks/patterns to work around it, it is neither elegant nor easy for maintenance.

Comment: Actually, "pure OO" has nothing to do with dynamic or static typing.  Don't let the name "objective-c" fool you.  C++ pretty much set the standard for object-oriented languages.